# In notepad++, can I paste a block of lines adjacent to the existing block of lines

Tags: vim, notepad++

## Existing file

```
aaaaaaaaa
nn
mm
kkkkkk
ll
o
```

I want another block of lines just next to this block of data. if I have few lines copied in the clipboard(either from same file or from a different file), I want those lines pasted just next to the existing lines without formatting the file(no new lines etc,..). If I have copied the below lines (either from this or a different file)

```
kk
lp
pl
oll
uu
```

I want that to be pasted to the file and file should look like this;

```
aaaaaaaaa     kk
nn            lp
mm            pl
kkkkkk        oll
ll            uu
o
```

If this is not possible in notepad++, can I do this in vim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Notepad++, you can do that like this:

1. Open the two files in Notepad++
2. In the second file, select everything you want to copy using column mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+select all the lines with the mouse).
3. Copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
4. Go to first file
5. Move the mouse at the end of the first line.
6. Add as many spaces as needed to reach the desired column number
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
8. Done.